# What are the 'oscillators' in the Drude Lorentz model?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, solid-state-physics

Jackson's Electrodynamics defines the Drude-Lorentz model as a set of harmonic oscillators (running over indices $j$ below), which, if you write out the equations of motion and rearrange a little, gives you the the famous DL equation for the permittivity of a material:

$$\epsilon(\omega) = \epsilon_0 + \frac{Ne^2}{m}\sum_j \frac{f_j}{\omega_j^2 - \omega^2 - i\omega \gamma_j}$$

($N$ = density, $f_j$ = oscillator strength, $\omega_j$ = resonant frequency for oscillator $j$, $\gamma_j$ = damping constant for oscillator $j$.)

Now the way he derives it, the electrons are simply oscillating spatially. But someone mentioned to me that the oscillations are actually transitions between different orbitals, which kind of makes sense to me: you could get the transition rates and such from Fermi's Golden Rule, and there's probably some analogy for the damping constant.

Is this true? Could it be that the derivation presented by Jackson is just a heuristic derivation which doesn't hold up in all possible cases? Or is it completely rigorous?

Comment: It seems impossible that a derivation is false, unless there is an error in it.

Comment: @Danu Well the derivation itself might be fine and work on a basic level, but give rise to erroneous behavior in some non obvious regime. I think analogously, the Bohr model of the atom works pretty well for a bunch of things, but eventually fails if you look closely enough.

Comment: This is certainly a heuristic derivation that has no reason to hold in general. The Drude model is classical to begin with and I think it is quite a bad start to be "rigorous". Now, the actual functional form you wrote is still extremely used as part of a fitting model in practice in engineering for instance because it is simple and carries some potential physical insights.

Answer (score 1):

> But someone mentioned to me that the oscillations are actually transitions between different orbitals, which kind of makes sense to me: you could get the transition rates and such from Fermi's Golden Rule, and there's probably some analogy for the damping constant. Is this true?

Lorentz-Drude model per se has nothing to do with transitions, orbitals or golden rule. It is a model based on the theory of electrons, where matter consists of charged particles that can move around, react to EM field and produce their own EM field.

The model was invented to explain optical properties of matter, mainly noble gases, and also electric behaviour of metals (when natural frequency is set to 0). There are no $f$'s here, or if you want them, they are all equal to 1.

In the optical case, formally similar formula for permittivity can be derived as an approximate result based on Schroedinger's time-dependent equation: 
$$
\epsilon = \epsilon_0 + \sum_{n}\sum_{m}'C \frac{N|\mu_{nm}|^2}{3 h}\frac{2\omega_{nm}}{\omega_{nm}^2-\omega^2}
$$
where $C$ is some constant. This formula is called the Heisenberg - Kramers formula since they guessed it (1924-1925) before Schroedinger derived it from his equation (one year later). There is no damping, no $\gamma$, no absorption, light is just scattered away to all directions.

If you want, you can make the two formulae look similar if you introduce $f$'s. They are not equal to 1 but their sum is equal to the number of the electrons in the molecule. These quantities $f_j$ were called oscillators strengths, so one can regard H-K formula as due to classical oscillators with strange charges $\sqrt{f_j} e$. Also the Heisenberg-Kramers formula has terms with negative signs which do not occur in the Lorentz-Drude formula.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite general expression for ${\epsilon}(\omega)$, based on causality. The complex Laplace transform $\hat{\chi}(z)$ with $Im(z)>0$ of the electric susceptibility $\chi(t)$ leads to an ${\epsilon}(z)$ that is analytic in the upper half plane. This makes it a Herglotz function and the latter have a representation as an integral over a measure $m(d\rho)$, $${\epsilon}(z)=\epsilon_0+∫m(d\rho)1/(\rho-z)$$.

$m(d\rho)$ in general consists of a sum of a point measure and an abolutely continuous (ac) one. Point measures are associated with dispersive, non-absorptive, systems and ac measures with absorptive ones. This is the most general expression for a causal linear system. As you will have noticed no specific model is required. A decade ago I wrote a paper (Phys. Rev. E **69**,
016610 (2004) about these matters. In Sect. 3 you will find the mathematical details.